# Эффект градиента под конец фона

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать эффект на html/css, который подчёркнут на картинке красным? [image]

Comment: Зачем задавать 2 одинаковых вопроса? 
http://hashcode.ru/questions/180939/html-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @lampa, вот-вот... и я о том-же,  и не только...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это очень просто.

> Создается рисунок в формате png
> (плитка либо фиксированной ширины),
> заливается он градиентной заливкой
> сверху в низ от определенного цвета
> **(скажем #dfdfdf)** переходя в прозрачны фон в  и далее слоем через
> z-index (как на картинке выше)
> перекрывает целевой контейнер имеющий
> цвет **#dfdfdf**